# How can I auto increment file name version in a bash shell environment?

Tags: bash

For context, I am building a Jenkins job to automatically git tag our branch code.  The idea is to construct a branch tag naming standard as follows:

```
<latest_tag_in_branch>.<branch_name>.<revision>
```

Let's assume a branch name of 'hotFix'.  If the latest tag doesn't include the branch name in it (e.g. `2.0.55`), then we should append this with a revision of 1.  E.g.

```
2.0.55.hotFix.1
```

If another tag was created on this hotFix branch without merging in any other code (and therefore the latest common tag doesn't change), then this becomes:

```
2.0.55.hotFix.2
```

If we then merge with master, which has subsequent tags created (e.g. let's say with 2.0.58 being the latest), then the next build of this branch would 'reset' to:

```
2.0.58.hotFix.1
```

The command:

```
git describe --abbrev=0 --tags
```

will get me the latest tag.  It would be, for example, either `2.0.55` or `2.0.55.hotFix.1`.  How can I proceed with this information in a bash shell environment to complete the rest of the tag name?  E.g. either append `<branch_name>.1` or increment the `<revision>` by 1.

My code so far:

```
> git describe --abbrev=0 --tags
```

(returns either e.g., 2.0.55, or 2.0.55.hotFix.3)

Being relatively inexperienced in bash, I'm unsure of the best approach on what to do next.

Comment: Please show what have you tried to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [pipe](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html) the output of your `git` command into another process which can manipulate the text (I'll prefer [`awk`](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/awk.html) here).

```
git describe --abbrev=0 --tags | awk -F. -v OFS=. '{
 if (NF == 3) $0 = $0".hotFix.1"
 else if (NF >= 5) $5 += 1
} 1'
```

What this does is that it will redirect the output from your `git` command into `awk` (as input).

1. We set the input and output delimiter to `.` by respectively doing `-F.` and `-v OFS=.`.
2. `awk` will run the script we provided in braces.
3. Our script will check if the input has three arguments (in the case of `2.0.55`). `NF` is a pre-defined variable that stores the **n**umber of **fields** in the input. `$0 = $0".hotFix.1"` will concatenate `.hotFix.1` onto the entire input (that's `$0`).
4. If the input doesn't have three arguments, we check that it has at least 5 arguments (`NF >= 5`). Then increment the fifth field by 1 (`$5 += 1`).
5. Finally, once the script has finished running, we print the statement by attaching a `1` after the closing brace. Note that if the input only had one or two fields, it would print the input unmodified.

<sub>Note that, you could also write your `awk` on a single line. I chose to write it on several lines since it's a tad more readable.</sub>

---

If you wish to use regex to check that the fifth field is an integer (before applying the `+= 1`, you could modify the `else if` to

```
else if (NF >= 5 && $5 ~ /^[0-9]*$/) $5 += 1
```

This will check that the number of fields (`NF`) is greater than 5 **and** check that the fifth field (`$5`) matches (`~`) a regex pattern (`/.../`) with a number (`[0-9]*`) from beginning (`^`) to end (`$`).

Comment: My low reputation doesn't allow me to upvote yet (?!), but +1 for sure.  That's a nice solution, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
branch_name="hotFix"                                 
example1="2.0.55.hotFix.1"                           
example2="2.0.55"                                    

regex_short="([0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+)"             
regex_long="($regex_short[.]$branch_name)[.]([0-9]*)"
for example in $example1 $example2; do               
  if [[ $example =~ $regex_long ]]; then             
    prefix=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}                        
    version=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}                       
    let ++version                                    
  elif [[ $example =~ $regex_short ]]; then          
    prefix=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}                        
    version=1                                        
  fi                                                 
  nvers="$prefix.$branch_name.$version"              
  echo "old_version: $example -> new_version: $nvers"
done
```

Comment: Nice to have another way to do this with regex.